# Show $E \cong E'$ as R-modules given $ h : N \to N'$ isomorphism, $\mathscr E : 0 \to N \to E \to M \to 0$ and its pushout

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $R$ be a ring, and consider an extension $\mathscr E : 0 \to N \to E \to M \to 0$ of $R$-modules.

If $h : N \to N'$ is a homomorphism, we can form the pushout

$h_*(\mathscr E ) : 0 \to N' \to E' \to M \to 0 $.

On the other hand, $h$ induces a homomorphism  $h_* : Ext^1_R(M, N) \to Ext^1_R(M, N')$.

Under this homomorphism, the class $[\mathscr  E ] \in Ext^1_R(M, N)$ is mapped to the class $[h_*(\mathscr E)] \in Ext^1_R(M, N')$.

In the above situation, if $ h : N \to N'$ is an isomorphism, show that $E \cong E'$ as R-modules.

**Any idea how to solve this?**

I think here I should use the fact that $Ext^1_R(M, N) \cong YExt^1_R(M, N)$, where $YExt^1_R(M, N)$ is what in my course was defined as the set of isomorphism clases in $YExt(M, N)$ and $YExt(M, N)$ is the category whose objects are extensions of the form $0 \to N \to E \to M \to 0$ and the morphisms are commutative diagrams

$0 \to N \to E \to M \to 0$

$\text{   }\text{   }\text{   }\text{   }\text{   }\text{   }\text{   }\downarrow{id}\text{   }$  $\text{   }\downarrow{f}\text{   }$   $\text{   }\downarrow{id}\text{   }$

$0 \to N \to E' \to M \to 0$

By definition, the pushout is related to the original extension by the diagram:

$0 \to N \xrightarrow{a} E \xrightarrow{b} M \to 0$

$\text{   }\text{   }\text{   }\text{   }\text{   }\text{   }\text{   }\downarrow{h}\text{   }$  $\text{   }\downarrow{\theta}\text{   }$   $\text{   }\downarrow{id}\text{   }$

$0 \to N' \xrightarrow{\alpha} E' \xrightarrow{\beta} M \to 0$

with $E'=h_*E=N'\oplus E/\{(h(n),-a(n))|n \in \Bbb N\}$

$ \alpha(n')=(n',0)$

$ \beta[n',x]=b(x)$

h is an isomorphism by assumption

I want to prove that $\theta$ is an isomorphism of modules
But I have no idea what to do with this

---

[image]

Comment: I am using this lecture notes by the way https://docdro.id/IarlBl1

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger I added some things, basically spelled out some definitions, Besides that I am clueless

Comment: Do you know a certain numerical lemma for when you have two SES and a map between them which consists mostly of isomorphisms?

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger The five lemma? (see picture)

Comment: The I guess is a direct application of the lemma that $\theta$ is an isomorphism correct? Since all assumptions are satisfied. Although I am not sue if the diagram is commutative by definition of the pushout?

Comment: It's something to be verified, but it follows from the universal property. Then the outside maps are all identity maps or isomorphisms, so the central map as is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint from the comments: Check that the diagram commutes using the universal property of the pushout, and then apply the Five Lemma.

Comment: Should I also verify that the second row (the pushout one) is short exact, or that's already takken for granted by definition of pushout?

Comment: It depends on how you constructed pushouts and what you know. If your definition is a specific kind of construction, it might be automatic. If your definition is a general category-theoretic thing, it might require another (very brief) observation to see the exactness.

Comment: Could you take a look at the follow-up to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4824784/e-kt-mod-show-that-either-e-cong-m-lambda-oplus-m-lambda-or-e-co ?